# Unix - Multiple Line csv Import to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, csv

I'm attempting to import a multiple line csv file into an Oracle database, through Unix using PLSQL.

Currently, my script below, converts the csv into an SQL string/file for another script to run SQL.

However, the script below is only suitable for one line csv's, can anyone suggest a way I can improve my below script for multiple line csv's please?

Thanks in advance.
Chris

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line ending with `> $1.sql` to `>> $1.sql`

Comment: That was so simple. Thanks.

Comment: sorry to ask, are you able to explain to me the difference between > $1.sql and >> $1.sql, please? Unix is still very new to me. Thank you.

Comment: `>` redirects the output to a (new) file and overwrites anything that's already there. `>>` appends to the file if the file is already there